# avoid autopost back asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

i am working on a web application using asp.net c#. it has multiple textbox controls like

TextboxA    TextboxB    TextBoxResult1
TextBoxX    TextBoxY    TextBoxResult2

i am doing some calculation on TextboxA,B,X,Y and displaying result to TextBoxResult1 and TextBoxResult2 using Ontextbox_change event.

my question is that On each calculation my page is going to refresh.i need to know how can i do this without auto post back . i don't want to use code other than c# like Ajax, java script, jQuery etc.

```
AutoPostback=true;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The code on a view is done at render and is then static html. In order to update the information you either do what you're doing (POST back) or use ajax to post back to the controller but only update specific information instead of refreshing the entire page. You could look into Blazor, but it's still experimental and not fully released (I can't comment on it, haven't used it myself yet).

Comment: Could you please let me know how do i find <asp:Panel> control using java script from string 
 for (var l = 1; l <= ddlSizesValue; l++) 
  {
        var Size = "pnlProduct1Design1Color1Size" + l;
        var pnl = document.getElementById('pnlProduct')
       var pnlSize = document.getElementById(Size);
        pnlSize.style.display = 'block';            
   }

in c# i am doing this by 

var Size = "pnlProduct1Design1Color1Size" + l;
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl pnlSize = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl)pnlProduct.FindControl(Size);

Comment: That would be a separate question that you need to ask.